# Django Python base.html for all templates

Tags: python, django, templates

In my root directory I have a template and inside that template follow by a `base.html` that would be my main layout for my custom admin site.

In my `templates/admin/base.html` I have this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Layout Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I want this `base.html` to be present in all my app templates.

I have an app `users` in my `mysite` project that its the index.html page.

[image]

inside my `users/views`.

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'users/index.html')
```

Inside my `templates/users/index.html` I have this.

```
{% extends "admin/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h1>Hello World</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

I get an error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /

I come from a node.js background so I have no idea if this is even a good practice. I have came across many tutorials explaining the use of templates inside an app but non explaining outside the app.

My understanding was that django bundles all templates into one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is 'admin/base.html'

Comment: in your ```index(request)``` function, try to use ```index.html``` instead of ```users/index.html``` . And my preference of organization of templates is: place all template in project in ```templates``` directory, and add ```my_app``` directory inside it, then add corresponding template in ```my_app``` , when i need to refer template, i user ```my_app\referred_template.html``` in my template or view function

Comment: you can just right click your templates folder and "mark directory as" > "templates directory"

Answer (score 4):

I figure it out. I need to add the global template my project settings.

```
'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
    ],
```