# How to have the same base.html template file for all of my modules?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am making a website for my church. I am using the django framework and I want to have a common base.html file throughout all my apps/models. Is there a way to make that happen?

I have tried using ../../ notation to get to a file that is in my main directory, but that raises the following error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: The relative path ''../../../sure_foundation_baptist /index.html'' points outside the file hierarchy that template 'main/index.html' is in.
```

main/templates/main/index.html

```
{% extends '../../../sure_foundation_baptist/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

sure_foundation_baptist/base.html

```
...
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

I expected it to extend the file correctly, but the actual output is the previous error.

Comment: Try moving base.html under templates.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: are you talking about main/templates?

Comment: if I put it under main/templates then I can't access it from my other apps I don't want to put the same base.html code in all my apps.

Comment: Ahh. Maybe something like this: [Django Python base.html for all templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703716/django-python-base-html-for-all-templates)? I don't know what your overall project structure is, but everything must be under 1 project. Then maybe you missed specifying the global base.html in DIRS.

Comment: Yes thank you so much!!!! I have been trying to figure this out for a while but now it works! I'm glad I joined stackoverflow!

Comment: I clicked the flag button. I thought that ment that your answer was the right answer but apparently not. Sorry for flagging you.

Comment: Great :) You can actually [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in case others stumble upon the same problem. I suggest specifying your directory structure and how you set the base template.

Comment: Oops! [Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) is for notifying moderators that something is bad. You can retract an incorrect flag. :)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: use up arrow to upvote when answer/comment is good, don't flag it.